# How to alter img src onclick using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple images with src URLs that all have

```
....content/..._gal6.jpg?format=100w
```

How can I use jQuery or JS to change all URLs to end with

```
?format=2500w
```

on click?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => {
  const url = new URL(img.src);
  if (url.searchParams.get("format")) {
    url.searchParams.set("format", "2500w")
    console.log(url.toString())
    img.src = url.toString()
  }  
})
```

```html
<img src="bla.jpg?format=250w">
<img src="bla.jpg">
<img src="bla.jpg?format=350w">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript:

Change the src property of the image:

```
function changeImage(){
document.getElementById('test-image').src = "https://url-to-second-image.com/image.png";
}
```

You can call the function using the click event in the html:

```
    <img id="test-image" src="the-url/first_image.jpg" onclick="changeImage()">
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5mwext3/2/

The same way you can change only part of the name (I'm using whole external files for convenience)